# define a function to look at unique value for certain column

Tags: pandas, function, count, unique

I am trying to define a function which takes a column name and find a counts of unique values within each column. I want this function to do this for 7 different data frames. I have tried the following code but I am getting this error AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'x'. I was wondering how should I define the function for it to work.

```
def valuecount(x):
   print(May_df.x.value_counts(),
   June_df.x.value_counts(),
   July_df.x.value_counts(),
   August_df.x.value_counts(),
   September_df.x.value_counts(),
   October_df.x.value_counts(),
   November_df.x.value_counts())
```

Comment: You need better tags - what is this? pandas? Something else? "function" is insufficiently descriptive.

Comment: Try:: `May_df[x].value_counts()...` instead.  The dot notation for dataframe columns has its weaknesses.

Comment: Thanks, I got it.